# Como retirar custom post types registrados da lista de custom fields?

Tags: wordpress

Boa noite!
Criei alguns custom post types através do comando register_post_type no wordpress, juntamente com os custom fields (post meta). O problema é que eles aparecem junto com os custom fields na edição das páginas (menu páginas), como eu faço para retirá-los de lá?

Eu gostaria que na edição de paginas aparecessem somente os custom fields de cada página e não os campos que criei para o post type.

Answer (score 2):

Sem ver o código que cria as meta-boxes a gente só tem como chutar.

Provavelmente em algum lugar do seu código tem uma chamada para [`add_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) em que o 4º parâmetro - `$screen` - está vazio, falso ou nem foi passado. Se você colocar o nome do post_type ele vai aparecer somente nas telas daquele tipo.

Comment: Segue o código:

Comment: ...
        register_post_type( 'banners' , $args );
} 

/** CADASTRO BANNERS */
add_action("admin_init", "iniciaBanners");

function iniciaBanners(){
    add_meta_box("Z_ordemBanner", "Ordem de Aparecimento do Banner", "Z_ordemBanner", "banners", "normal", "low");
}

Comment: eu coloquei o post type "banners" para aparecer somente naquele tipo de post type... mas ele está aparecendo nos custom fields de todas as páginas...

Comment: hm, pode não ser isso, mas vi que vc tá chamando `add_meta_box` dentro da action `admin_init`. A action correta é `add_meta_boxes`, coisas estranhas acontecem se vc liga num gancho cedo demais.

Answer (score 2):

Para que seus *Custom Fields* não apareçam na lista de um post/página/CPT, tem que usar um *underscore* no principio do nome.

Por exemplo, isto *aparece* na lista: `meu_custom_field`. Isto *não* aparece: **`_meu_custom_field`**.

Comment: Perfeito! Esta solução resolveu o meu problema!